# Simplify SQL query which uses `row_to_json`

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using [`row_to_json`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) function available in PostgreSQL 9.3 to get a query result as JSON:

```
SELECT row_to_json(_customer_wishes) FROM (
    SELECT
        ...
        (SELECT row_to_json(_brand)
            FROM (
                SELECT b.id, b.name, b.url
            ) AS _brand
        ) AS brand,
    JOIN brand AS b ON ...
    WHERE ...
) AS _customer_wishes;
```

However I don't like `(SELECT row_to_json(_brand) FROM (SELECT b.*) AS _brand ) AS brand`.

I would like something like `(SELECT row_to_json(SELECT b.*)) AS brand`, but I am not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use types for situations like this (we use database in a object oriented way).

Just for example:

```
CREATE TYPE type_brand AS
(
    id integer,
    name text,
    url text
);
```

And your subquery:

```
SELECT row_to_json(SELECT (b.id, b.name, b.url)::type_brand) AS brand.
```

But, with table structure and desidered result I think I can suggest a more elegant query, where you can use row_to_json just once.